# Problem with post data with Ajax popup - asp.net core

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core

I have a problem with ajax posting data.
let me explain .. I have a simple form to post "Category" using ajax call to Insert and Update data, every thing works fine 100%, except one thing.

**The Problem**
After update the record, it's updating fine and popup hide, but if I click on new Record, the popup show up with the value for last update record instead of null values form, it's keep the values from last update, I dont know why?

**My Code**

```
<form asp-action="AddOrEdit" asp-route-id="@Model.CategoryId" onsubmit="return jQueryAjaxPost(this);" autocomplete="off">

            <input type="hidden" asp-for="CategoryId" />

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CategoryId" class="control-label"></label>
                <input id="CategoryId" asp-for="CategoryId" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CategoryName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input id="CategoryName" asp-for="CategoryName" class="form-control"></input>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group submit-div">
                <input id="SubmitForm" type="submit" value="حفظ" class="button-insert-model" />
            </div>
        </form>

[HttpGet]
        [NoDirectAccess]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddOrEdit(int id = 0)
        {
            if (id == 0)
            {
                return View(new Category());
            }
            else
            {
                var cat = await _db.Categories.FindAsync(id);

                if (cat == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                return View(cat);
            }

        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddOrEdit(int id, [Bind("CategoryId, CategoryName")] Category category)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (id == 0)
                {
                    _db.Add(category);
                    await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        _db.Update(category);
                        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
                    }
                    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                    {
                       
                    }
                }

                return Json(new
                {
                    isValid = true,
                    html = Helper.RenderRazorViewToString(this, "_ViewAll", _db.Categories.ToList())
                });
            }
            return Json(new { isValid = false, html = Helper.RenderRazorViewToString(this, "AddOrEdit", category) });
        }


<div class="insert-button-div">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
    <a onclick="showInPopup('@Url.Action("AddOrEdit","Home",null,Context.Request.Scheme)','Add Cat')">Add Cat</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="table-div-grid text-center">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CategoryId)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CategoryName)
                        </th>
                        <th>

                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @item.CategoryName
                            </td>
                            <td class="td-operations">
                                <a onclick="showInPopup('@Url.Action("AddOrEdit","Home",new {id=item.CategoryId}, Context.Request.Scheme)','Edit Record')" class="button-edit-table">Edit</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


showInPopup = (url, title) => {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        success: function (res) {
            $('#form-modal .modal-body').html(res);
            $('#form-modal .modal-title').html(title);
            $('#form-modal').modal('show');
        }
    })
}

jQueryAjaxPost = form => {
    try {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: form.action,
            data: new FormData(form),
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function (res) {
                if (res.isValid) {
                    $('#view-all').html(res.html)
                    $('#form-modal .modal-body').html('');
                    $('#form-modal .modal-title').html('');
                    $('#form-modal').modal('hide');
                }
                else
                    $('#form-modal .modal-body').html(res.html);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        })
    } catch (ex) {
        console.log(ex)
    }
    //to prevent default form submit event
    return false;
}
```

Comment: just like you see, we have showInPopup method which would fill the form before it's `show`. I'm afraid we can troubleshoot it with following steps: 1 make sure we could clear the form manually by comment `$('#form-modal').modal('hide');` so that we could see if it worked. 2 debug the code to see if the `showInPopup` method received expected response(empty or has value). The issue might result from failing to clear the form or filling the form with unexpected data. Could you pls help confirm it?

Comment: could you pls show us the code snippet about `Get AddOrEdit`, checking the `res` returned by this get method, I'm afraid it contains value.

Answer (score 0):

Updated:

If the form is not resetting even after using `$(form)[0].reset();`, there might be a couple of reasons for this behavior. Let's try a different approach to manually clear the form fields. Modify your success callback as follows:

```js
success: function (res) {
    if (res.isValid) {
        $('#view-all').html(res.html);
        // Clear form inputs manually
        $(form).find('input[type=text], input[type=hidden]').val('');
        $('#form-modal .modal-body').html('');
        $('#form-modal .modal-title').html('');
        $('#form-modal').modal('hide');
    } else {
        $('#form-modal .modal-body').html(res.html);
    }
},
```

This modification uses `$(form).find('input[type=text], input[type=hidden]').val('');` to manually clear text and hidden input fields. Adjust the selector based on your form structure if needed. Try this and see if it resolves the issue of retaining values after the update.

Old:

It looks like you might be facing an issue with the form not resetting after successfully updating a record. To resolve this, you can modify your success callback in the jQueryAjaxPost function to reset the form after a successful update. You can do this by clearing the form inputs. Here's an example modification:

```js
success: function (res) {
    if (res.isValid) {
        $('#view-all').html(res.html);
        // Clear form inputs
        $(form)[0].reset();
        $('#form-modal .modal-body').html('');
        $('#form-modal .modal-title').html('');
        $('#form-modal').modal('hide');
    } else {
        $('#form-modal .modal-body').html(res.html);
    }
},
```

Adding `$(form)[0].reset();` after updating the HTML content will reset the form inputs, preventing the issue of retaining values from the last update. Try incorporating this change and see if it resolves the problem.

Comment: unfortunately it's not working, still keep the values after update.

Comment: Check my updated answer, hope it will work.

Comment: I already test to clear the input manually before, and try your code now, but form still keep the values.

Answer (score 0):

**The Answer**

Finally i catch it, I change the Add new record button to another simple function, but I change ajax url to this specific action instead send it in button event. it's working

The code

```
<a onclick="showInPopup2('Add Cat')">Add Cat</a>

showInPopup2 = (title) => {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'Home/AddOrEdit',
        success: function (res) {
            $('#form-modal .modal-body').html(res);
            $('#form-modal .modal-title').html(title);
            $('#form-modal').modal('show');
        }
    })
```

}